# What does 'or' mean?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

I don't get this sentence at all. I thought the 'or' was the French starting to use English words more and more in their language but as 'or' it doesn't seem to make sense.

```
si c'est pas possible y'aura pas d'interaction or ce 1er avril 2017 est basé sur l' interaction
```

I've heard 'or' used at other times by the French and it seemed to be equivalent to the English meaning but here I didn't quite get it.

Comment: *Or* can have [two different meanings](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/or/forced) depending on the word being a noun or a conjunction. From the place in the sentence you can tell it is not a noun, so it is the conjunction (meaning two in the link). *Or* in French can never have the meaning of the English word "or".

Comment: OK I see, so if you were to replace 'or' here in this sentence with another French word without changing the meaning, what word (or words) could it be?

Comment: "Or" is mainly to link two opposite arguments so "Mais" can be used but that not really the same things exaclty.

Comment: I thought it meant 'or' because google translate translates it to 'or' in English...but it particularly didn't seem to make sense in this sentence which lead me to inquire here. Strange since google translate is really quite good these days, well for French anyway.

Comment: The google translation is in fact "if it is not possible there will be no interaction or this 1 April 2017 is based on the interaction".  Strange it did all the hard parts perfectly but for some reason had no idea about what 'or' was supposed to be.

Comment: I always found the most useful one-word translation was "now", in the sense: "It is well-known that interaction with another culture develops a better awareness of one's own. **Now**, if a student develops an obsession with a foreign culture, she may neglect to learn key details of her own." Unfortunately that's not the most common word/definition in English either, but if you're comfortable with it then it serves quite well for French *or*. Incidentally, the given sentence is missing helpful punctuation around *or*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this specific case, an alternative word could be 'cependant':

> si c'est pas possible y'aura pas d'interaction or ce 1er avril 2017 est basé sur l' interaction

In this context I'd translate 'or' by 'however':

> If it's not possible there'll be no interaction, however this April 1st 2017 is based on interaction.

On a side note, "or" never means the english "or" and the translation for the english "or" is "ou".

Taken from laure's comment [here's the two meanings](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/or/forced) of the french "or", wordreference has also [some interesting example](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/or)

After comment I tried with a better formulation and punctuation on Google translate :

> si ce n'est pas possible il n'y aura pas d'interaction, or ce 1er avril 2017 est basé sur l' interaction

which gives something better:

> if this is not possible there will be no interaction, but this April 1, 2017 is based on the interaction

Comment: Ok thanks for your explanation. I guess the other times I came across 'or' it could have meant 'or' but here it really didn't fit at all. Add to that the fact google translate translates it to 'or' in English....not sure why it does that since its generally pretty accurate these days what with all the community help they have with it.

Comment: The google translation is in fact "if it is not possible there will be no interaction or this 1 April 2017 is based on the interaction".  Strange it did all the hard parts perfectly but for some reason had no idea about what 'or' was supposed to be.

Comment: @Hasen I saw that and submitted the alternative I used here ;)

Comment: @Tensibai I played a bit with google translate, and turns out it has some pretty specific rules to recognize "or": it has to be at the beginning of a sentence, and followed by a comma. "or, ce 1er avril 2017 est basé sur l' interaction" correctly translates to "however, this April 1, 2017 is based on the interaction". This does not match all of the french uses of "or" though.

Comment: @Kerkyra indeed, played after your comment and Luke's one under the question and edited accordingly

Comment: @Kerkyra ok I see, that's interesting to note. I must say I was surprised when it didn't get that part since its been really quite accurate generally. Well at least its a very useful tool in language learning.

Comment: Actually I just came across another sentence with 'or' in it and adding a comma changed the English translation from 'or' to 'gold'....so it actually still didn't work that well. Its quite strange, google translate just doesn't get what 'or' means in French any better than I did!

Answer (score 5):

It's one of the 7 *[conjonctions de coordination](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjonction_de_coordination#Conjonction_.C2.AB_or_.C2.BB)* ("mais, ou, et, donc, or, ni, car" -- which list I was taught in school using the mnemonic, "Mais où est donc 'ornicar'?"):

> La conjonction **or** est la conjonction de coordination dont l'emploi est le plus flou. Elle indique généralement une idée d'opposition et s'apparente ainsi à la conjonction « mais »
>
> Tout le monde admire Léonard dans le village. Or on ignore généralement qu'il est profondément dépressif.
> C'était un homme prévoyant. Or il lui arriva ce qu'il redoutait le plus.

I'd usually translate it as "however" or "on the other hand" (but the examples above I might translate as "consequently").

> Elle est fréquemment utilisée pour mettre en relation deux arguments desquels on va ensuite tirer une déduction :
> Tous les hommes sont mortels. Or Socrate est un homme. Donc, Socrate est mortel.

That means something like "whereas".

Answer (score 0):

In the top sentence, or: yet.
If it's not possible, there won't be any interaction, yet this April 1st, 2017, is based on interaction.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).